# Setting v-for to a Specific Index

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm fairly new to Vue, so please bear with me if this is a stupid question.

I have a large array of images which I am outputting to the screen as a sort of film reel using this code:

```
images = [
    {src: 'image1.jpg'},
    {src: 'image2.jpg'},
    {src: 'image3.jpg'},
    {src: 'image4.jpg'},
    {src: 'image5.jpg'},
    ...etc
];

<div v-for="(img, index) in images" :key="index">
   <img :src="img.src" />
</div>
```

**edit:** What is produced is a horizontal strip of images. The image of interest should be at the centre of the screen with as many images visible either side as the screen width will allow (typically four or five at the moment). The required index comes from elsewhere in the code. I can get the value of the index to output in the v-for loop no problem, but I can't seem to get it to change the position of the loop.

So far so good, this outputs the collection in the way I want it to. What I would like to do, however, is to go to a specific image on the reel when I supply the appropriate index, so I guess the question is whether it is possible to go to a specific image/index in the v-for loop programmatically?

Any help or pointers in the right direction would be gratefully received.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean "go to a specific image"? Scroll to its position? Wrap the list to start at that index?

Comment: Hi, ideally I'd like to scroll to its position, but I would accept either behaviour at this point.

Comment: Is this a slider, a horizonta list of images, a vertical list of images, is only 1 image being shown at a time, do you simply want to scroll the page to an image. How is the selection being done, through an input field a dropdown, etc. We need way, way, way more information to be able to do anything with this.

Comment: edited to add some info. I realize that the question is a little sketchy, but so is my current knowledge of Vue, so I'm still a bit unsure exactly how to phrase what I'm after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell how'd you'd need to implement this specifically from your lack of code. But, whatever way you do it, you'll probably want to use [`$refs`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Child-Component-Refs). Putting a [`ref` attribute](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref) on the same element as the `v-for` will create an array of reference to those elements indexed in the same order. From there you can set the scroll based on your needs.

Here's an example:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      items: [
        {text: 'a'},
        {text: 'b'},
        {text: 'c'},
        {text: 'd'},
        {text: 'e'},
        {text: 'f'},
        {text: 'g'},
        {text: 'h'},
      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    scrollTo(index) {
      let $item = this.$refs.item[index];
      let $container = this.$refs.container;
      $container.scrollTop = $item.offsetTop;
    }
  }
})
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }

.container {
  background: #fafafa;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.4/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="container" ref="container">
    <div v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index" ref="item">
      {{ item.text }}
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <button v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index" @click="scrollTo(index)">
    {{ item.text }}
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!